# Loading textures from another class.XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I'm having the following issue:
I want to load my texture from my player class.
So I'll do the following in my player class:

```
   public void Load(ContentManager Content)
    {
        Content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/pong");
    }
```

And I'll do this in my main class;

```
MyPlayer.Load(Content);
        MyPlayer = new Player(new Vector2(500, 700), Bat,new Vector2(5,5),new Vector2(Bat.Width / 2,Bat.Height/2),graphics);
```

But it says that I have to use the new keyword before I can use methods(and I understand that). What can I do to fix that, and load textures properly from another classes?

Answer (score 0):

Simply swap the 2 instructions and save the texture somewhere (you're loading it but not assigning to any variable):

```
MyPlayer = new Player(new Vector2(500, 700), Bat,new Vector2(5,5),new Vector2(Bat.Width / 2,Bat.Height/2),graphics);
playerTexture = MyPlayer.Load(Content);

...

public Texture2D Load(ContentManager Content)
{
    return Content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/pong");
}
```

Comment: I haven't really understood what you're saying, mind showing it to me with a code sample please?

Comment: Listen, "Bat" is supposed to be my texture. When I'm trying to compile the code it throws me an excepction saying: you need to use the "new" keyword... and whats the point of making playertexture if it isnt in the constructor(which means i can't use it as a texture in my class?)

Comment: @Joe: this makes me think you don't actually know what's a constructor's purpose.

Comment: The constructor's purpose is to initialize the fields of the class, isn't it?

Comment: @Joe: yep, but it also executes some other code besides what you write, it actually _creates_ the class. That's why you have to call it first

Comment: I'm aware of that I suppose to create the "new" keyword first, and that's what I'm doing, hold on let me show you what's the problem.

Comment: @Joe: it happens because when you call player's constructor, you pass in Bat which is null (not initialized). You can't do that, because to load Bat player must be initialized, and to initialize player you need Bat. You should change the design of your code

Comment: I undestand that now, you mean that I use methods of an uninitalized class. Alright, you got any idea how I should fix that, or change the design of the code, as you said?

Comment: @Joe: well, why do you want to load a texture in another class? Just use Game.Content.Load<>() ;)

Comment: I want my code to be well arranged. There's no other way than loading the texture in the Game1 class then?

Comment: @Joe: you can load it everywhere with Game.Content.Load<>().

Answer (score 0):

What "Bat" is? Also, you have to first call MyPlayer = new Player(...), and then call MyPlayer.Load().

I'd recommend doing something like this:

```
MyPlayer = new Player(POSITION, Content.Load<Texture2D>("PathWhereBatIs"), new Vector2(5,5),graphics);
```

and then in Player constructor to get origin of Bat-texture do this:

```
public Player(Vector pos, Texture2D tex, Vector2 ??, GraphicsDevice device)
{
    Vector2 Origin = new Vector2(tex.Width / 2f, tex.Height / 2f);

    ...
}
```